# Can we set random() function upper limit to infinity in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, upperbound

Can we set upper limit of random function to infinity, means that there is no upper limit for random() function and it sets its upper limit automatically from infinite numbers each time we use it.

If not random() function, is there any other function that can do this?

Comment: Would `random() * sys.maxsize` be ok ?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361811/how-to-generate-n-random-numbers-in-python-3-between-0-to-infinity

Comment: You might have to wait a **very** long time to get an answer.  How many billions do you have to buy more storage to hold the number when you eventually get it?

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import sys
x = random.randint(0, sys.maxsize)
```

Comment: It generates a constant number each time i call it.

Comment: Each time you call it in the same program, or each time you re-run the same program? It might be a seeding issue in the latter case.